# SQL- How to put your Row result as a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a script that has a result of 3 rows only:

```
SELECT U.LEVEL FROM USER U

 1. ADMINISTRATOR
 2. STANDARD USER
 3. LIMITED USER
```

Now what i want is to look like as a column in the result of the script. please see below:

```
ADMINISTRATOR | STANDARD USER | LIMITED USER
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: I can't help thinking we'd be able to help more if you give us some context. If you do this you'll distort the data, what happens if you add another role? It'll break the query! Why exactly do you need these as columns?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard SQL in the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your question is not complete. You stated you wanted them to be the column names, but have not said what values you like. With your input, the following is a possible solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT [LEVEL]
         FROM [USER]
     ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT(
         MAX([LEVEL])
         FOR [LEVEL] IN ([ADMINISTRATOR], [STANDARD USER], [LIMITED USER])
     ) AS PivotTable;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb95dc/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is what im looking for, i tried this one before but i forgot the PIVOT in sql. Could you please give me reputation so that i could upvote you.

Comment: I am really sorry to say that reputation is earned, not asked for. But you should also know that reputation is earned even by accepting answers (if you find the one that did the trick for you), or even by asking awesome questions. The best way to earn reputation though would be giving your answer to other people's questions. That would help you build up not only rep, but also your skills and confidence. There are many out there that would gladly downvote you.... but this is too a part of the learning process.

Comment: well said, so i guess i would wait for it to upvote until i reach 15. glad to know that your not on rush to upvote because you nailed what im looking for.